# AWS amplify codegen: Namespace API has no exported member

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli, graphql-codegen

My web app uses AWS resources, for example a Cognito user pool and an AppSync GraphQL API. These resources are maintained in a separate project. Whenever they are modified, I delete them using `amplify` and re-import them:

```
$ amplify remove auth
   ...
$ amplify remove api
   ...
$ amplify import auth
   ...
$ amplify codegen add --apiId <my API ID>
   ...
```

As far as I can tell, that is the canonical way to importing externally managed resources; if anyone knows a better way, please share. This approach has worked ok-ish so far for a couple of months.

However, after the most recent delete / re-import, running the app fails with a compiler error in the TypeScript code generated by `amplify codegen`:

```
$ yarn start

Compiled successfully!
 ...
webpack compiled successfully
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
ERROR in src/graphql/queries.ts:21:30
TS2694: Namespace '"<path to project>/src/API"' has no exported member 'SomeAPIOperationQueryVariables'.
    19 |   }
    20 | }
  > 21 | ` as GeneratedQuery<APITypes.SomeAPIOperationQueryVariables, APITypes.SomeAPIOperationQuery>;
       |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    22 | export const anotherAPIOperation = /* GraphQL */ `query AnotherAPIOperation {
    23 |   anotherAPIOperation {
    24 |     color

ERROR in src/graphql/queries.ts:32:30
TS2694: Namespace '"<path to project>/src/API"' has no exported member 'AnotherAPIOperationQueryVariables'.
    30 |   }
    31 | }
  > 32 | ` as GeneratedQuery<APITypes.AnotherAPIOperationQueryVariables, APITypes.AnotherAPIOperationQuery>;
       |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    33 |

ERROR in src/graphql/subscriptions.ts:25:12
TS2724: '"<path to project>/src/API"' has no exported member named 'AThirdAPIOperationVariables'. Did you mean 'AThirdAPIOperation'?
    23 | }
    24 | ` as GeneratedSubscription<
  > 25 |   APITypes.AThirdAPIOperationVariables,
       |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    26 |   APITypes.AThirdAPIOperation
    27 | >;
    28 | export const aFourthAPIOperation = /* GraphQL */ `subscription AFourthAPIOperation {

ERROR in src/graphql/subscriptions.ts:39:12
TS2724: '"<path to project>/src/API"' has no exported member named 'AFourthAPIOperationSubscriptionVariables'. Did you mean 'AFourthAPIOperationSubscription'?
    37 | }
    38 | ` as GeneratedSubscription<
  > 39 |   APITypes.AFourthAPIOperationSubscriptionVariables,
       |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    40 |   APITypes.AFourthAPIOperationSubscription
    41 | >;
    42 |
```

The AppSync API and its schema (as well as the Cognito resources) have been used successfully in several separate independent projects for a couple of months, so they seem unlikely to be the cause of the issue.

The compiler error occurs for those four API GraphQL operations that don't take arguments (because they don't need any). For all the other queries, mutations and subscriptions that *do* take arguments, the corresponding types are generated in `API.ts` and the code compiles ok.

I tried importing as described above; also tried starting over by deleting any local files related to `amplify` plus any live AWS cloud resources and running `amplify init` again; also tried checking out the repo again (just in case I missed any hidden amplify files). Error persists.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here ? Does anyone have any advice how to go about even diagnosing the issue properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I had/have a similar issue as well. Unfortunately, it seems like a bug in the Amplify codegen tool that seems to be assuming every query takes arguments of some kind. Or at the very least, it's not generating the Variables type with an empty dict for the input.

I'm not sure if there's an already existing issue on their GitHub, but I think I'll make one today if there isn't by the time I get to it.

My temporary workaround is to just add  a dummy optional argument to each query in the schema file so that it generates the Variables types. You can even give them default values IIRC.

I know that's not the ideal solution. But hopefully it helps you get past the issue for the time being.

Comment: Looks like someone has the same issue and submitted a bug report: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-codegen/issues/733. Care to +1 ?

Comment: my current workaround is to downgrade the amplify-cli to 12.4.0

Comment: I install the amplify CLI using `brew install aws-amplify`: With 12.4.0, the error persists; with 12.3.0, the generated code seems to compile.